# What am I doing wrong with my use of _().any()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to refactor the following code to use .filter() and .any(). Where am I going wrong??

The goal is to return all pizzas that do not contain nuts or mushrooms. In both instances, productsICanEat.length should === 1.

**Original Code:**

```
products = [
   { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
   { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
   { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
];

var i,j,hasMushrooms, productsICanEat = [];

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i+=1) {
    if (products[i].containsNuts === false) {
        hasMushrooms = false;
        for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j+=1) {
           if (products[i].ingredients[j] === "mushrooms") {
              hasMushrooms = true;
           }
        }
        if (!hasMushrooms) productsICanEat.push(products[i]);
    }
}
```

**Refactored Code:**

```
var productsICanEat = [];

  /* solve using filter() & all() / any() */
  productsICanEat = _(products).chain()
              .filter(function(product) { 
                if(product.containsNuts === false) 
                  return product; 
                })
              .any(function(product) {

                if(product.ingredients.indexOf('mushrooms') === -1)
                  return true;
                else
                  return false;

              }).value();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just with [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter). The function used by the `filter` iterator should return a boolean value based on whether it should be included in `productsICanEat`:

```
productsICanEat = _(products).chain().filter(function(product) { 
    return !product.containsNuts && (product.ingredients.indexOf('mushrooms') === -1); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Nearly identical to Dogbert's answer. I'm trying to understand .any() though and figure out why my code isn't working (even though it isn't ideal).

Comment: `any()` returns a `true` if the evaluating function returns `true` for "any" members of the collection, and `false` if none of them return `true`. It's useful for getting a true/false value, not for narrowing down the list. When you call `.values()` on the result from `any()`, you're calling it on a boolean value rather than on an underscore object, which of course won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating it.

```
var productsICanEat = _(products).filter(function(product) {
    return !product.containsNuts && product.ingredients.indexOf("mushrooms") === -1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/Ap9LR/

Comment: Thanks! What am I doing incorrectly with .any() though? I'd like to get this to work so that I understand it, even if it's not the best way.